# Close file after running py script

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I have some code that gets the names of files in a location and then exports to csv. However, I can't delete that file after the code is finished running and file explorer says it's being used by another program. I assume bc my code didn't explicitly say to close the file. here's my code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
#set working directory
os.chdir('path')

# get file names
list = os.listdir()
# turn into array
a = np.asarray(list)
#write it out
a.tofile('foo.csv',sep=',')
```

I assume `a.close()` would work but it's telling me numpy.ndarray object has no attribute 'close'.

Comment: Did you try this `filename = "foo.csv"` after that run `filename.close()`

Comment: Are you using the command `open()`, if yes, are you using the statement `with open() as myvar:`? Maybe that helps.

Comment: `'foo.csv'` is not also open for editing/viewing in Microsoft Notepad or another editor? If so, need to close any other applications using `'foo.csv'` Check in the Task Bar or Task Manager